# Can I read Locators(web elements, selectors etc) from Excel file instead of Properties file?

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I have somehow managed to read the excel using POI libraries however not able to figure out how to put them in a hashmap and where to add the cell and rows in hashmap. Also how to call them in my selenium script.

```
public void readValueFromExcel()
    {
        Iterator<Row> rowiterator=shSheet.iterator();
        while (rowiterator.hasNext())
            {
            HashMap<String, String> xHashmap = new HashMap();
            Row nextRow = rowiterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> celliterator= nextRow.cellIterator();
                while (celliterator.hasNext())
                    {
                    Cell nextCell = celliterator.next();
                    switch (nextCell.getCellType())
                        {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(nextCell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(nextCell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                        }
                    //System.out.print(" - ");

                    }
                //System.out.println();

            }
```

Comment: Why not just put all the locators in your code? Are they going to change often or ? You could just put them in a CSV file and quickly read that. You can even use Excel to quickly create or edit the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Create an excel file with two columns - Locator Name and Locator Value (Like you do Key=Value in your .properties file). Create a method to read that excel file. search for a value given for key (Locator name) and then return its preceding cell's value (Locator Value).

Also you can write one singleton that will read the excel file in start of the execution and store it into a `HashMap` and then you can get desired Locator value as and when required.

You can make it further dynamic by putting type of locator also as a third column and specify weather the locator is name, id, xpath or cssId. In this case your method should return appended string of "Locator value+type". You need to write another method that will retun ,`By`, object respective to type defile in excel and the you can use it in your `driver.findElement...`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How can I call this value from the excel then. earlier I used to call the getproperty method and use the object file.

Comment: @SuvinGanjoo Have a look at Apache POI project to access Excel files. Pretty simple...

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. I have figured out how to use the POI extension. The only thing I want to understand is that how to parse the data from Excel (eg, Xpath etc) as specified by @QA Square . Do I need to pass the row number and column number of that locator in driver.findelement while parsing the data from Excel? For example, I want the value to 2nd row and 1st column to be used as an XPath, how would I pass it in driver.findelement?  I hope my question is clear?

Comment: You will add a "Locator Name" in your script(that will be at cell[0] in your excel) and then will find for its respective value in excel. Hence you need to first write a loop that read through cell[0] of all the rows and whenever you get it, you need to read the value of cell[1] of that row. That will be your "Locator value"

Comment: That is why I suggest to read all the excel data in one go and store in a HashMap. Than you can provide the Key value that is Locator Name and will vet the respective value (Locator Value)